# ESXI Hardware RAID Solution

Tags: raid, software-raid, esxi, hardware-raid

I'm re-purposing a machine to run ESXI and made a rookie error in that I did not properly understand the hardware requirements. The machine will run a range of linux distros which will then runner Docker.

In summary, the RAID controller on my main board is not compatible with ESXI and despite having RAID 1 configured on the main board, ESXI sees two physical drives. An obvious problem in retrospect that would have been discovered in around 10 seconds with a search engine.

I'm now looking at corrective actions as I would like to run RAID 1 on this machine.

I've read I can install a HP P410 RAID controller which I can get cheaply enough 2nd hand from eBay.

1. My mini ITX main board (GA-Z270N) has 1 x PCIe 16 socket. The HP controller is a PCIe 8 socket. I've read I can put the x8 into an x16 socket and it should negotiate. Would this be correct?
2. My drives are SATA and I understand the HP card will be SAS. I've read I can use a SAS/SATA breakout cable to make the connection but unsure if I need just a `breakout cable` or a `reverse breakout cable`.
3. Does the RAID controller need to be installed from day 1? Or can I start to configure the system (taking a risk) with one disc and no RAID controller, then fit the RAID controller and it will mirror disk 1 to disk 2?

Comment: PCI-E x16 is compatible with PCI-E x8.  If you only have one disk then you will be unable to even initialize the RAID array

Comment: Generally, for hardware RAID, you need to initialize RAID from day 1.  You might be able to create a new degraded RAID1 array with one disk though.

Comment: SATA should work on your SAS controller with the right cable.  I have consumer drives in trays in an enterprise server with SAS controller.  Should is the operative word though.  Just buy the parts and try if they are so cheap.